# Why are my variables being alerted back to me as null?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Why are my variables being alerted back to me as null?

So, I'm trying to pass a string in a variable back to a main page from an external javascript page via alerts.

At first I thought that the javascript wasn't pulling information from the php page properly, then I tried just typing in a variable directly on the javascript page. Both the pulled information and the information that I described on the javascript directly send null.

Now I know for a fact that the varibles name and email are not null, as I literally just defined them.

Here is the code I am having an issue with.

```
let name = "test";
let email = 11;
let company = document.getElementById($("#Company").value);
let phone = document.getElementById($("#Phone").value);
let city = document.getElementById($("#City").value);
let state = document.getElementById($("#State").value);
let country = document.getElementById($("#Country").value);

alert("Test Alert");
alert(name);
alert(email);
alert(company);
alert(phone);
alert(city);
alert(state);
alert(country);
```

Here is the full javascript file:

ROICalc3.js

```
const getErrorMsg2 = lbl =>
  `${lbl} must be a valid percent less than or equal to 100.`;

const focusAndSelect = selector => {
  const elem = $(selector);
  elem.focus();
  elem.select();
};

const processEntries = () => {
  let ActiveNumberOfMolds = parseFloat($("#activeNumberOfMolds").value);
  let PercentOfDownMolds = parseFloat($("#percentOfDownMolds").value);
  PercentOfDownMolds = PercentOfDownMolds * .01;
  let AverageLaborHours = parseFloat($("#averageLaborHours").value);
  let RepairRatePerHour = parseFloat($("#repairRatePerHour").value);
  let CostOfCurrentLifter = parseFloat($("#costOfCurrentLifter").value);
  let AverageProfitPerPressHour = parseFloat($("#averageProfitPerPressHour").value);
  let EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter = parseFloat($("#estimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter").value);
  let PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters = parseFloat($("#percentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters").value);
  let AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold = parseFloat($("#averageNumberOfLiftersPerMold").value);
  PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters = PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters * .01;
  let LifterCostDifference = (EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter - CostOfCurrentLifter);

  if (isNaN(ActiveNumberOfMolds) || ActiveNumberOfMolds <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter The Active Number Of Molds"));
    focusAndSelect("#activeNumberOfMolds");
  } else if (isNaN(AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold) || AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the Average Number Of Lifters Per Mold:"));
    focusAndSelect("#averageNumberOfLiftersPerMold");
  } else if (isNaN(PercentOfDownMolds) || PercentOfDownMolds <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the Percentage Of Down Molds:"));
    focusAndSelect("#percentOfDownMolds");
  } else if (isNaN(AverageLaborHours) || AverageLaborHours <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the Average Labor Hours:"));
    focusAndSelect("#averageLaborHours");
  } else if (isNaN(RepairRatePerHour) || RepairRatePerHour <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the repair rate per hour:"));
    focusAndSelect("#repairRatePerHour");
  } else if (isNaN(AverageProfitPerPressHour) || AverageProfitPerPressHour <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the average profit per press hour:"));
    focusAndSelect("#averageProfitPerPressHour");
  } else if (isNaN(CostOfCurrentLifter) || CostOfCurrentLifter <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the average profit per press hour:"));
    focusAndSelect("#costOfCurrentLifter");
  } else if (isNaN(EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter) || EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the estimated price of an acculifter:"));
    focusAndSelect("#estimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter");
  } else if (PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters <= 0) {
    alert(getErrorMsg("Enter the percentage reduction in lifter failure using accualign lifters:"));
    focusAndSelect("#percentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters");
  } else if (PercentOfDownMolds > 1) {
    alert(getErrorMsg2("Enter the percentage of down molds:"));
    focusAndSelect("#percentOfDownMolds");
  } else if (PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters > 1) {
    alert(getErrorMsg2("Enter the Percentage Reduction In Lifter Failure Using Accualign Lifters:"));
    focusAndSelect("#percentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAccualignLifters");
  } else {
    $("#MRRPA").value = (ActiveNumberOfMolds * PercentOfDownMolds);
    let mrrpa = parseFloat($("#MRRPA").value);
    $("#ANHPL").value = (mrrpa * AverageLaborHours);
    let anhpl = parseFloat($("#ANHPL").value);
    $("#ALCRFLPM").value = ((anhpl * RepairRatePerHour) + (mrrpa * CostOfCurrentLifter * AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold));
    let alcrflpm = parseFloat($("#ALCRFLPM").value);
    $("#PLDDM").value = (AverageProfitPerPressHour * anhpl * .3);
    let plddm = parseFloat($("#PLDDM").value);
    let eacfl = (plddm + alcrflpm);
    $("#EACFL").value = (eacfl);
    $("#CDBCLVAL").value = (EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter - CostOfCurrentLifter);
    let pldtd = (PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters * plddm);
    let cdbclval = parseFloat($("#CDBCLVAL").value);
    $("#TCDBCLVAL").value = (cdbclval * (ActiveNumberOfMolds * AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold));
    let tcdbclval = parseFloat($("#TCDBCLVAL").value);
    let acrnm = ((anhpl * RepairRatePerHour * PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters) + (EstimatedPriceOfAnAcculifter * AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold * ActiveNumberOfMolds * PercentOfDownMolds * PercentageReductionInLifterFailureUsingAcculignLifters));
    let cdnlptrc = (tcdbclval + acrnm + pldtd);
    let rlfcical = (eacfl - cdnlptrc);
    $("#RLFCICAL").value = rlfcical;
    $("#EMUUPI").value = ((tcdbclval / rlfcical) * 12).toFixed(2);;
    let emuupi = parseFloat($("#EMUUPI").value);
    console.log("EACFL: " + eacfl);
    console.log("cdnlptrc: " + cdnlptrc);
    document.getElementById("MRRPA").innerHTML = mrrpa + " Molds";
    document.getElementById("ANHPL").innerHTML = anhpl + " Hours";
    document.getElementById("ALCRFLPM").innerHTML = "$" + alcrflpm;
    document.getElementById("PLDDM").innerHTML = "$" + plddm;
    document.getElementById("CDBCLVAL").innerHTML = "$" + cdbclval;
    document.getElementById("TCDBCLVAL").innerHTML = "$" + tcdbclval;
    document.getElementById("RLFCICAL").innerHTML = "$" + rlfcical;
    document.getElementById("EACFL").innerHTML = "$" + eacfl;
    document.getElementById("EMUUPI").innerHTML = emuupi + " Months";
    document.getElementById("ACRNM").innerHTML = "$" + acrnm;
    document.getElementById("PLDTD").innerHTML = "$" + pldtd;
    document.getElementById("CDNLPTRC").innerHTML = "$" + cdnlptrc;

    if (rlfcical > 0) {
      document.getElementById("RLFCICAL").style.color = "green";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("RLFCICAL").style.color = "red";
    }
    if (eacfl > 0) {
      document.getElementById("EACFL").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("EACFL").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (alcrflpm > 0) {
      document.getElementById("ALCRFLPM").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ALCRFLPM").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (plddm > 0) {
      document.getElementById("PLDDM").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("PLDDM").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (tcdbclval > 0) {
      document.getElementById("TCDBCLVAL").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("TCDBCLVAL").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (cdbclval) {
      document.getElementById("CDBCLVAL").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("CDBCLVAL").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (emuupi > 0) {
      document.getElementById("EMUUPI").style.color = "green";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("EMUUPI").style.color = "red";
    }
    if (anhpl > 0) {
      document.getElementById("ANHPL").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ANHPL").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (mrrpa > 0) {
      document.getElementById("MRRPA").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("MRRPA").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (acrnm > 0) {
      document.getElementById("ACRNM").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ACRNM").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (pldtd > 0) {
      document.getElementById("PLDTD").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("PLDTD").style.color = "green";
    }
    if (cdnlptrc > 0) {
      document.getElementById("CDNLPTRC").style.color = "red";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("CDNLPTRC").style.color = "green";
    }

    let name = "test";
    let email = 11;
    let company = document.getElementById($("#Company").value);
    let phone = document.getElementById($("#Phone").value);
    let city = document.getElementById($("#City").value);
    let state = document.getElementById($("#State").value);
    let country = document.getElementById($("#Country").value);

    alert("Test Alert");
    alert(name);
    alert(email);
    alert(company);
    alert(phone);
    alert(city);
    alert(state);
    alert(country);

    let result = document.querySelector('.result');

    // Creating a XHR object 
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "https://staging-dmecompany.kinsta.cloud/Submissions/submitjson.php";

    // open a connection 
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);

    // Set the request header i.e. which type of content you are sending 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Create a state change callback 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        // Print received data from server 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };

    // Converting JSON data to string 
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      "Name": name,
      "Email": email,
      "Company": company,
      "Phone": phone,
      "City": city,
      "State": state,
      "Country": country,
      "ActiveNumberOfMolds": ActiveNumberOfMolds,
      "PercentOfDownMolds": PercentOfDownMolds,
      "Average Labor Hours": AverageLaborHours,
      "RepairRatePerHour": RepairRatePerHour,
      "AverageProfitPerPressHour": AverageProfitPerPressHour,
      "AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold": AverageNumberOfLiftersPerMold,
      "rlfcical": rlfcical,
      "LifterCostDifference": LifterCostDifference,
      "anhpl": anhpl,
      "alcrflpm": alcrflpm,
      "plddm": plddm,
      "cdbclval": cdbclval,
      "pldtd": pldtd,
      "cdbclval": cdbclval,
      "emuupi": emuupi,
      "mrrpa": mrrpa,
      "acrnm": acrnm,
      "pldtd": pldtd,
      "cdnlptrc": cdnlptrc
    });
    // Sending data with the request 
    xhr.send(data);
  }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  $("#calculate").addEventListener("click", processEntries);
  $("#activeNumberOfMolds").focus();
});
```

Can you tell me why these variables are getting alerted back to me as null?

Edit: #1:
I tried swapping the code to this:

```
    let name = "test";
let email = 11;
let company = document.getElementById("Company").value;
let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
let city = document.getElementById("City").value;
let state = document.getElementById("State").value;
let country = document.getElementById("Country").value;

alert("Test Alert");
alert(name);
alert(email);
alert(company);
alert(phone);
alert(city);
alert(state);
alert(country);
```

The first alert had, "test"
The second alert had, "11"
All of the rest of the alerts were, "Undefined".

The alerts seem to be feeding back data now if the variables are described in the javascript code itself. I don't seem to be able to pull them from my php file.
[image]

Comment: # is for CSS selectors or querySelector. Don't use it with document.getElementById

Comment: In fact, in newer web browsers, you actually don't need this at all. If you set an element with id = "foo", you can then just use foo as a JavaScript variable (non-strict mode)

Comment: What is `$` in your application? Is it jQuery or an abbreviation for `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: @ControlAltDel That's not a "newer browsers" thing, it's an ancient JavaScript feature. It's a bad idea to depend on it, because IDs that conflict with other window properties will not work that way.

Comment: That's good to know. I believe I'd copied the syntax off of it when I had started importing the numbers back to the page. I know that the # aren't causing this specific issue because I defined a few of these by hand, namely, the variable name and email and both of those also failed. This information you gave me might be crucial later when I go to import the information from my php page to the javascript page though! So thank you for it.

Comment: The $ in my application is for jquery I think. The initial purpose of this page was to be a calculator to process roi info. The php page sends data over to this page using ids. Then jquery on this page pulls them and manipulates the data and sends it back. Here is a link to an earlier version of this: https://www.dme.net/accualign-roi-calculator/  The new version I am working on will be to take data from a form that users need to submit info on to access the page and pass that information to this javascript file to be added to a big csv along with the user inputs.

Comment: ControlAltDel, what do you mean I don't need it at all? Is there some way I can see what the variables are set to on my external javascript page? The idea behind these alerts is to use them for testing to make sure that the data I am sending from my first page gets to the second one. If there is a way to check this information without doing an alert or something I'd be very grateful to hear of it.

Comment: If `$` is jQuery then the syntax is `$(selector).val()`.

Comment: "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and ***the shortest code necessary*** to reproduce the problem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.value` should not be in the argument to `document.getElementById()`, it should be used on the *result* of this.

And you shouldn't call `$()` or use the `#` prefix in the argument to `getElementById()`, the argument should just be the ID by itself.

```
let company = document.getElementById($("#Company").value);
```

should be

```
let company = document.getElementById("Company").value;
```

Or if `$()` is an abbreviation for `document.querySelector()`, you can write

```
let company = $("#Company").value;
```

If it's jQuery, then the correct syntax is

```
let company = $("#Company").val();
```

Comment: So I tested your syntax and it is coming back as undefined through the alerts.  let name = "test";
 let email = 11;
 let company = document.getElementById("Company").value;
 let phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
 let city = document.getElementById("City").value;
 let state = document.getElementById("State").value;
 let country = document.getElementById("Country").value;
 
 alert("Test Alert");
 alert(name);
 alert(email);
 alert(company);
 alert(phone);
 alert(city);
 alert(state);
 alert(country); @barmar

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: yes, though the errors are for sending the information to phpfile #2 through xhr. I believe it's because I am sending variables that are undefined to the php page. Once I can figure out how to get my variables from the first php page to this javascript page and get them into variable format it should solve this issue.   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (ROICalc3.js:243)

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you're getting `undefined` in the alerts. If the element can't be found you'll get an error about trying to access a property of null. If the input isn't filled in, the valule will be an empty string, not `undefined`.

Comment: Before I switched to your synatx, it wouldn't give me, name or company, which I defined on the javascript page. I think you resolved the issue that my questions was about. Now I still have to figure out how to get data to the php, but, technically speaking this wasn't what I asked. Is there any possibility you might know what I am doing wrong to get these readings of undefined?

Comment: The error about `innerHTML of null` is because there's no element with `id="result"`

Comment: If `$` is jQuery you have a bunch of other problems. `parseFloat($("#activeNumberOfMolds").value)` should be `parseFloat($("#activeNumberOfMolds").val())`

Comment: `value` is a DOM property, `val()` is the analogous jQuery method.

Comment: so I just tested this on the live site on the working version and it has this same console error, https://www.dme.net/accualign-roi-calculator/ Its an element that appears to be just sitting unused that I never noticed. I'm not sure if it's having an effect on any of the rest of this stuff. That calculator tool is pulling it's data just fine though. I think I never ended up using that results element.

Comment: So, the jquery section for active mold is working just fine and doing the job I need it to do, so I'm hesitant to touch it because generally speaking I don't want to break something new before I solve the other issue.  That jquery line is present on this page: https://www.dme.net/accualign-roi-calculator/ and it pulls the input for the active number of molds field and then I manipulate it and it affects most of the values in the lower section.

Comment: The error happens on this line: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=this.responseText;` but there's no `result` element anywhere.

Comment: So, it definitely is an error. But if it makes any sense. I've been managing to pass information from the php page to the javascript page using jquery, though when I pass the strings to the page, they are getting marked as undefined. I don't believe I use that result element anywhere either, I just haven't touched it as it's not hurting anything and I'm afraid of breaking something else before I fix the first issue I am out to repair.

Comment: There's way too much code in the question. Please reduce it to a [mcve] that just demonstrates the specific problem you want help with.

Comment: I added a <p id="result"></p> at the bottom and it cleared out the console errors.

Comment: I think you answered my initial question, I think what I will do is make a new question in 90 minutes with the second part.